# How do I search all my code + imported libraries in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm pretty happy with VSCode's code navigation but sometimes I want to go further and search text in all the code of imported libraries.

For now, I can search all the code in the current project directory but if the imported libraries are not in the current project directory, say `Anaconda/`, I can't search the code inside `pytorch` even though I can import it in my code.

So what I want to do is to enable search in the current development environment with all the external libraries, not limited to my own code inside my project directory. (Of course I would be able to search installed libraries if I have `venv/` inside my project directory but I want to do the search even if I don't directly have `venv/` inside my project directory.

I heard that it is possible in PyCharm so I hope there's something equivalent in VSCode.

How do I extend VSCode's search scope to ALL the libraries currently being imported in my project? (or better yet, all the libraries that I'm able to import)

Comment: then start a Multi Root workspace and add the other directories you want to search

Comment: @rioV8 But that's not what it's built for. Multi root workspaces are meant to be used for projects that have project files in multiple directories, not for dependency files.

Comment: but the file search searches all defined workspace folders. You only use stuff where it is build for? Then a lot of useful IKEA Hack Videos are not for you.

Comment: What I mean is that because the multi-root workspace is not built for this purpose, it will have limited functionalities and will be prone to unintended behavior whenever I try to do something. Seems like there's no equivalent feature in VSCode yet. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122082

Comment: I ended up opening the whole new VSCode instance in my venv (in my case Anaconda env) directory instead. Shame I can't search only imported libraries & navigate code within my project's VSCode instance but at least it works.

Comment: write a task that searches the wanted directories, output something you can parse with a problem matcher and use the PROBLEMS panel to view the errors, that is what I did to get a very custom search functionality, the task starts a python script